# How to add rounded edges to a-plane (Aframe) Web VR

Tags: aframe

How can i  add rounded edges/border radius to a a-plane?

`<a-plane position="1 0.75 -3" geometry="width: 1.25; height: 1.25;depth: 1.25;"></a-plane>`
i have to make a square with rounded edges

Comment: It seemed like someone had to write code just to get [a rounded rectangle](https://github.com/etiennepinchon/aframe-rounded), so maybe it's not within A-Frame to give rounded edges?

Comment: Well i  have to make a square with rounded edges is there anyway around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rounded corners with `a-plane` is not possible. You can use the [slice9 component](https://github.com/fernandojsg/aframe-slice9-component)

[image: slice9]

Answer (score 1):

The "easy" suggestion in this case would be to create a rectangle graphic with rounded corners and save it as a png file. This image should be used as the texture of the plane.

Make sure that you use `material="transparent:true"` in the a-plane tag to ensure that no background shows behind the rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, if this is a one off and simply for visual effects, your best option is to make a custom texture and simply texture the plane.

However, if you require multiple or need it to interact with other elements, then you would be better off creating a custom geometry or component. There is an example on the three.js website on [how to extrude a flat square into an beveled object](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/ExtrudeBufferGeometry). You could [create a custom component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/component.html#register-a-component) and feed it the length and width, this would then let you use the regular material options on it too.